# Very simple Node.js POST form inquiries

Tags: node.js, express, nodemailer

I have a simple node.js app using express static and nodemailer with a POST form that emails the filled fields to myself. My problems are very simple, I'm just quite new to Node so I can't find a way to do them.

My first problem is that I can't find a way to put all the form data into the email's text. Below, I am trying to store my form data in a JSON and call it in the email text, but it doesn't work. It has only correctly worked for me when I only used one variable (ex. just req.body.name) for the text. How can I format my data together in the email?

My second problem is that I can find a way to handle the app after the email is sent. I want it to redirect to a success page, as shown in the marked line, but it does not work. Instead, the page goes to /reqform and displays an error message saying success.html doesn't exist (it is in the same public folder as my html file). I believe the problem lies in my sendFile usage, but I'm not sure.

```
app.post('/reqform', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
    response = {
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        phone: req.body.phone
    };
    var mailContent = {
        from: 'myemail@gmail.com',
        to: 'myemail@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Service Request From req.body.name',
        text: response               //*** Problem #1
    };
    transporter.sendMail(mailClient, function (error, info) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            res.sendFile("success.html");   //** Problem #2
        }
    });
})
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: test probably requires a string, and you're sending it an object. That doesn't format well. Emails are finnicky because making sure they're formatted typically means ugly code. As for the other, how are you exposing your public directory?

Comment: Do you have a [body parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) installed? That might be easier than manually jamming in `urlencodedParser`.

Comment: Is there a way to send a string with all three variables? And my public directory contains my html files all on the same level. I'll try out body parser, its just that right now I'm just using the bare minimums to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The default string value for a JavaScript Object [is just `"[object Object]"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString). If you want anything else, you'll have to be specific with how you want it represented.

   For example, JSON is a text/string format that represents values like Objects. It's separate from the Object itself, so you'll need to convert to use it:

   ```
   var mailContent = {
       // ...
       text: JSON.stringify(response)
   }
   ```

   Or, provide your own formatting:

   ```
   var mailContent = {
       // ...
       text: `Name: ${response.name}\nEmail: ${response.email}\nPhone: ${response.phone}`
   }
   ```
2. It might be better to use [`res.redirect()`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.redirect) in this case, allowing the client/browser to request `success.html` via your application's `static()` middleware:

   ```
   res.redirect('/success.html');
   ```

   [`res.sendFile()`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendFile) doesn't collaborate with any `static()` middleware to know about your `public` folder. It expects you to provide a full path either directly or with its `root` option:

   ```
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/success.html'));
   ```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed.